# What is the recommended way to downmix 5.1 or 7.1 to 2.1?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stereo, 5.1

I've been trying to downmix a 5.1 DTS HD-MA (specifically arranged as `C L R Ls Rs LFE`) track into 2.1 (with LFE), but I'm not sure of the recommended/standard way that doesn't mess up the audio.
I first extracted the audio alone into an `mka` container, and then ran:

```
ffmpeg -i "audio.mka" -c dca -vol 256-af "pan=stereo|FL=0.5*FC+0.707*FL+0.707*BL+0.5*LFE|FR=0.5*FC+0.707*FR+0.707*BR+0.5*LFE" "audio-stereo.mka"
```

But I get an error: `-vol has been deprecated. Use the volume audio filter instead`

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this.
I also want to downmix to 2.1 other immersive tracks (Atmos/DTS-X and maybe some regular 7.1 as well), is that possible using ffmpeg or it is not supported? I'm just not familiar with these commands in general.

Comment: Best way to not mess up the audio is to just play it back on a device that's only 2.1-capable. It will do it on the fly.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not all devices do though, which is precisely the point of what I'm trying to accomplish. If it worked, I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: These are two questions. (1) The "best" way probably depends on how the audio is laid out for the particular file - different coefficients will give different (and better/worse, depending on your taste) downmixing results. So experiment. I am also not sure you want LFE in the FL/FR mix if you have 2.1. (2) Quick googling finds docs on how to use the [volume audio filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume) instead of `-vol`. (3) Is there a space missing between `256` and -`af`?